# How to working onclick event on div including iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onclick

How to fire `onclick` event when click the image ?
and one limitation is that I can't modify testcode2.html.

now the `href` properties only work.
please help me :( !!

```
<script>
    function go()
    {
         alert("Hello World!");
    } 
</script>
<div href="#" onClick="go()">
  <iframe src="testcode2.html" />
</div>
```

`testcode2.html` is as follows:

```
<a href="http://translate.google.com">
<img src="http://cdn01.cdn.pinkisthenewblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/071712_findingnemosequelfeat-250x250.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: is testcode2.html on the same domain as your main html ?

Comment: no. they are different domain each other

Answer (score 3):

This might help you http://jsfiddle.net/fjGJ5/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".frame").on('click', call);
});

function call(){
alert("I am called.");
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="frame">
    <iframe src="http://www.jsfiddle.net/" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: you can transfer the same script to your iframe page and it will run.

Comment: hey I looked, It is not working in your case. I figured out that it requires empty space in the iframe to work on. I can help you if you let me know what exactly you want to do.?

Comment: oh really thanks Mayank Tripathi :) actually i want to catch a click of a adsense ad. adsense ad ('a'tag)will be made in iframe, so when click the ad in iframe i want to call a method written in parent page.

Answer (score 2):

Give the div an ID and then fire the onClick event using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#divIFrame").click(function(){
    alert("Hello World");
    });
 });
</script>
<div href="#" ID="divIFrame">
  <iframe src="testcode2.html" />
</div>
```

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double in the binding :          $( '#divIFrame').click(function(){

Answer (score 0):

Move your script on testcode2.html

```
<a href="javascript:go()">
<img src="http://cdn01.cdn.pinkisthenewblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/071712_findingnemosequelfeat-250x250.jpg"/></a>
```

Then make the redirect by javascript after alert

Answer (score 0):

To call a Javascript function defined in parent use `window.parent`

```
<a href="http://translate.google.com" onclick="window.parent.go();">
    <img src="http://cdn01.cdn.pinkisthenewblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/071712_findingnemosequelfeat-250x250.jpg"/>
</a>
```

You might want to stop the redirect in which case add a `return false` to your go() function and then use `onclick="return window.parent.go();"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("test_frame").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = function(){
      alert("Hello World!");
    };
  };
</script>

<iframe id="test_frame" src="testcode2.html" />
```

EDIT: If you cannot use getElementById(), querySelector() or getElementsByTagName() may work.

```
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = function(){
          alert("Hello World!");
        };
       /* document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.onclick
= function(){
          alert("Hello World!");
        }; */
      };
    </script>

    <iframe id="test_frame" src="testcode2.html" />
```

Comment: thanks! but actually iframe will be created dynamically so, i can't give 'id' to iframe

Comment: If you cannot use an id, I thought you may want to use querySelector() or getElementsByTagName() instead to find the iframe.